# How do I get my header to line up at the top of the browser?

Tags: html, css

When I insert my header background image it does not line up exactly to the top of the browser.  There is a space between the header image and the top of the browser showing the background color.  I want the Header to go all the way up to the top of the screen, and to not show any background color.

```
   /* CSS Document */

html, body, {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
       font: 12px/16px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
       color: #000;
       background-color:#426fac;

}

/*** header
****************************************/
#header {
    background: url(images/header-bg.png) no-repeat center top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

ANy ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What about some HTML, or link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to define whatever element your header is (h1/div/?) has having 0 margin also -- many elements have margin built in, and that may be causing the space you're seeing, as #header is obviously attached to *something*

Comment: html, body, header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

Comment: that was not the problem ... the problem was an extra comma (,) in the first rule causing it to fail..

Answer (score 1):

There is an element with non-zero margin/padding that you're not accounting for.  If you post your markup, I may be able to help identify it.  This could easily be a default value that you're not setting yourself... even for the  tag.

Or you could use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  Just select the #header element and review the CSS definitions that the browser is applying to it.  It may be #header or it may be a parent/ancestor of header.

Comment: I'd recommend using Firebug to quickly check what is causing the problem. Just use the Inspect feature of Firebug, point your cursor to the space, and you should see which element and CSS lines are causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have an error in your css

you need to remove the last comma (,) from the `html,body, {` and make it `html,body {`

Currently the first css rule about html and body fails due to it ..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `#header` to the list `html, body`, which get `margin: 0; padding: 0`.